# How to implement this flowchart as C program code

Tags: c

I am looking to implement this flowchart using C. I don't know how to do it.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bg80F.jpg)

I tried to do it but I couldn't unfortunately this is not my area of expertise. I did like this but I don't know what is missing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int b, c, i, newb, newc;
    printf("Enter two integers: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &b, &c);
    for(i=20; i >= b + c; --newb)
    {
        if(b+c%i==0)
   printf("the new value of b and c: ");
 scanf("%d %d", &newb, &newc);      
    }
    printf(" %d and %d is %d", b, c, newb, newc );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no need for a `for loop` in here since there is no way to go back in the flow chart.

Comment: The diamond (typically a decision yes or no) can be used as an if/else, if the condition is true, do the yes part, otherwise use the no portion in the else.

Comment: so can you help me and edit the code for the if else im not so good at c language to be honest

Comment: Please provide images directly visible.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Enter b and c: ");
    int b, c;
    // this is reading into b and c
    scanf("%d %d", &b, &c);
    // we use an if statement to represent yes/no decisions
    if (20 >= b + c) {
        c = c + 3; // or c += 3
        b = b * 2; // or b *= 2
        // we print c and b with labels
        printf("c: %d, b: %d\n", c, b);
    } else {
        // not quite sure what write b <- b - 1 is supposed to mean
        // but I'm guessing it means decrease b by 1 and print
        b = b - 1; // or b -- or b -= 1
        printf("b: %d", b);
    }
    printf("Whatever ID is supposed to mean\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Turkii you should not thank, you should accept the answer (if it solved your issue).